# SSO/Authentication for PowerBI Custom Visuals

Tags: powerbi, single-sign-on, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm creating a Custom Visual for PowerBI.

Can you please advise on how to perform Single Sing On (SSO) for users who are going to consume data using a Custom Visual?

I need to get the user's session token in order to trigger some backend processes using the Custom Visual.

Your help is appreciated.